# (int, const char *) as a compound key with the uthash library

Tags: c, string, pointers, hashtable, uthash

I would like to use the [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) library for a hash table with a pair of `int` and `const char *` as a compound key:

```
typedef struct entry_s {
    // This field is needed by the uthash library
    UT_hash_handle hh;

    // Values
    /* ... */

    // Compound key
    int num;
    const char *str;
} entry;
```

Specifically, I want the string pointed by `const char *` to be a part of the key. To clarify: the different values of a pointer may correspond to the same string (in the sense of `strcmp()`).

The [userguide](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_compound_keys) shows how to implement a key that is similar to what I want with an `int` and `char[]` as a compound key:

```
typedef struct another_entry_s {
    // This field is needed by the uthash library
    UT_hash_handle hh;

    // Values
    /* ... */

    int str_len;

    // Compound key
    int num;
    char str[];
} another_entry;
```

However, the second approach (i.e., `(int, char[])`) assumes the string is copied to `char[]`, but I would like to avoid the copying.

Also, I'm not looking for concatenating `int` and string pointed by `const char *` in order to leverage `HASH_ADD_KEYPTR()` and `HASH_FIND_STR()` convenience macros.

I cannot figure out how to use `HASH_ADD()`, `HASH_FIND()`, and other general macros, with the first approach (i.e., `(int, const char *)`). It looks like it is impossible to avoid copying, as by the uthash library design. Do I understand that right? Or is there a non-copy approach that I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible with the design of this library (and it's impossible with *any generic* implementation without copying).

For any hashtable implementation, you need to apply some hashing function to some data. So you could of course write your *specific* implementation where the hashing function uses the bytes of an integer field **and** the bytes of a string some other field points to. But if your hashtable implementation is *generic*, your only option for a hashing function would be something similar to this:

```
unsigned int hash(void *data, size_t size);
```

The prototype doesn't have to look *exactly* like this, but in any case, the input is a pointer to *some* data (of any type) and the size of that data. So, obviously, you can't make such a function read from two different locations at once.

According to [the uthash documentation](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_compound_keys), uthash solves the problem of *compound keys* by requiring them to consist of adjacent struct members. The data is then read from the first of these members with a size that includes all the members **and padding**. The documentation of the library is aware of that problem and requires that the struct must be initialized to all zero, e.g. with `memset()`, so the padding bits have defined values. If you want to use this, you **must** make your string a member of the structure (instead of a pointer to it).

While this probably works fine in most implementations, I personally wouldn't rely on that feature **at all**, because the C standard doesn't guarantee a defined value of padding after setting some member, see

**C11 (draft N1570), §6.2.6.1 p6**:

> When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member
>   object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take
>   unspecified values. [...]

---

The really safe and portable way to use your compound key with this library is therefore: take a concatenated copy of the data. You could do something like this, given your struct above with one added field `char *hashKey`:

```
#define ENTRY_KEYLEN(str) (sizeof(int) + strlen(str))
#define ENTRY_GETKEY(key, e) (getEntryKey((key), (e)->num, (e)->str))

static void getEntryKey(char *key, int num, const char *str)
{
    memcpy(key, &num, sizeof num);
    memcpy(key + sizeof num, str);
}
```

Then you could use the uthash macros like this:

```
entry *entries = 0;

entry *myent;
// allocate space, fill data in myent

// store in hashtable:
char *key = malloc(ENTRY_KEYLEN(myent->str));
// check key for NULL
ENTRY_GETKEY(key, myent);
myent->hashKey = key;
HASH_ADD_KEYPTR(hh, entries, key, ENTRY_KEYLEN(myent->str), myent);

// [...]

// find in hashtable
const char *str = "foo";
int id = 42;
key = malloc(ENTRY_KEYLEN(str));
// check key for NULL
getEntryKey(key, id, str);
entry *found;
HASH_FIND(hh, entries, key, ENTRY_KEYLEN(str), found);
free(key);
```

---

You *might* be better off using a different generic hashtable implementation that makes your usecase a bit easier, e.g. by using some *callback function* to retrieve the hash key data.

Comment: Right. "[Your key can even comprise multiple _contiguous_ fields](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_compound_keys)" - this is how the compound key should look like.

Comment: @AlexanderPozdneev as I said, while it's **very** unlikely that assigning to some struct field changes *padding* bits in some unpredictable manner, the C standard would allow such behavior, so I wouldn't use this feature for portability.